# Expand time series data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, linear-interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate between time points for all data in a pandas dataframe. My current data is in time increments of 0.04 seconds. I want it to be in increments of 0.01 seconds to match another data set. I realize I can use the DataFrame.interpolate() function to do this. However, I am stuck on how to insert 3 rows of NaN in-between every row of my dataframe in an efficient manner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Time": [0.0, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12], 
                        "Pulse": [76, 74, 77, 80],
                        "O2":[99, 100, 99, 98]})
df_ins = pd.DataFrame(data={"Time": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                            "Pulse": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                            "O2":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

I want df to transform from this:

```
    Time    Pulse   O2
0   0.00    76      99
1   0.04    74      100
2   0.08    77      99
3   0.12    80      98
```

To something like this:

```
    Time    Pulse   O2
0   0.00    76      99
1   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN     NaN
4   0.04    74      100
5   NaN     NaN     NaN
6   NaN     NaN     NaN
7   NaN     NaN     NaN
8   0.08    77      99
9   NaN     NaN     NaN
10  NaN     NaN     NaN
11  NaN     NaN     NaN
12  0.12    80      98
```

Which I can then call on

```
df = df.interpolate()
```

Which would yield something like this (I'm making up the numbers here):

```
    Time    Pulse   O2
0   0.00    76      99
1   0.01    76      99
2   0.02    75      99
3   0.03    74      100
4   0.04    74      100
5   0.05    75      100
6   0.06    76      99
7   0.07    77      99
8   0.08    77      99
9   0.09    77      99
10  0.10    78      98
11  0.11    79      98
12  0.12    80      98
```

I attempted to use an iterrows technique by inserting the df_ins frame after every row. But my index was thrown off during the iteration. I also tried slicing df and concatenating the df slices and df_ins, but once again the indexes were thrown off by the loop.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resample` here (replace `ffill` with your desired behavior, maybe mess around with `interpolate`)

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"], unit="S")
df.set_index("Time").resample("0.01S").ffill()
```

---

```
                 Pulse   O2
Time
00:00:00            76   99
00:00:00.010000     76   99
00:00:00.020000     76   99
00:00:00.030000     76   99
00:00:00.040000     74  100
00:00:00.050000     74  100
00:00:00.060000     74  100
00:00:00.070000     74  100
00:00:00.080000     77   99
00:00:00.090000     77   99
00:00:00.100000     77   99
00:00:00.110000     77   99
00:00:00.120000     80   98
```

---

If you *do* want to interpolate:

```
df.set_index("Time").resample("0.01S").interpolate()
```

---

```
                 Pulse      O2
Time
00:00:00         76.00   99.00
00:00:00.010000  75.50   99.25
00:00:00.020000  75.00   99.50
00:00:00.030000  74.50   99.75
00:00:00.040000  74.00  100.00
00:00:00.050000  74.75   99.75
00:00:00.060000  75.50   99.50
00:00:00.070000  76.25   99.25
00:00:00.080000  77.00   99.00
00:00:00.090000  77.75   98.75
00:00:00.100000  78.50   98.50
00:00:00.110000  79.25   98.25
00:00:00.120000  80.00   98.00
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works wonderfully and is very fast. The only thing I added was to convert the Time index back into a float with `df = df.set_index(df.index.total_seconds())`. This may not be the most logical, but it works for the other half of my coded interface which is expecting a float rather than a datetime.

Comment: Also, thanks for showing me the ffill() method. I didn't know I could use that, and it may actually be what I need in the future. Its good to have the option of ffill() or interpolate()

Answer (score 1):

I believe using np.linspace and process column-wise should be faster than interpolate (if your Time column is not exactly in time format):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

new_dict = {}
for c in df.columns:
    arr = df[c]
    ret = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        ret.append(np.linspace(arr[i-1], arr[i], 4, endpoint=False)[1:])
    new_dict[c] = np.concatenate(ret)
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_dict)]).sort_values('Time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    Time    Pulse   O2
0   0.00    76.00   99.00
1   0.01    75.50   99.25
2   0.02    75.00   99.50
3   0.03    74.50   99.75
4   0.04    74.00   100.00
5   0.05    74.75   99.75
6   0.06    75.50   99.50
7   0.07    76.25   99.25
8   0.08    77.00   99.00
9   0.09    77.75   98.75
10  0.10    78.50   98.50
11  0.11    79.25   98.25
12  0.12    80.00   98.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! This is more of the solution that I was looking for. You were astute enough to realize my Time column isn't actually time, but just an incremental float. However, after having tested @user3483203 answer theirs is indeed faster than this approach.